# Connect pyroscope to grafana datasource using .yaml config files and docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, grafana, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

## Status

- Trying to integrate `pyroscope` to `grafana` using `.yaml` configuration file.
- At local stage, it works well. But on cloud infrastructure, it does not work.

---

## Configuration files

`grafana-datasource.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: Pyroscope
    type: phlare
    basicAuth: false
    editable: true
    access: proxy
    uid: phlare
    url: http://pyroscope:4040
    version: 1
    jsonData:
        minStep: '15s'
        backendType: 'pyroscope'
```

`pyroscope-local-config.yaml`

```yaml
storage-path: "/var/lib/pyroscope"

retention: 360h # 15 days
exemplars-retention: 72h # 3 days

scrape-configs:
  job-name: pyroscope
  scrape-interval: 10s
  enabled-profiles: [cpu, mem]
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    hostname: "grafana"
    container_name: "grafana"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/grafana-datasource.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasources.yaml
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
    networks:
      - pyroscope

  pyroscope:
    hostname: pyroscope
    container_name: pyroscope
    image: "pyroscope/pyroscope:latest"
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"
    command:
      - "server"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/pyroscope-local-config.yaml:/etc/pyroscope/server.yaml
    networks:
      - pyroscope

networks:
  pyroscope:
    name: pyroscope
    driver: bridge
```

---

## Network configuration in cloud infrastructure

[image]

---

## What I did for resolving this issue?

### reading documentary related grafana and pyroscope

- I read but still I don't know what is the root cause

### allowing all traffic from TCP in cloud infrastructure console

- didn't work

### changed configuration files

- didn't work too

---

## What I want to do

### Integrate the pyroscope into grafana like this

[image: grafana on local stage]
Well-integrated grafana with pyroscope datasource at local
[image: grafana on cloud infrastructure]
But it does not integrated when I deploy on cloud infrastructure

### Error logs

```bash
logger=accesscontrol.evaluator t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67422445Z level=debug msg="matched scope" userscope=datasources:* targetscope=datasources:uid:phlare
logger=datasources t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67432201Z level=debug msg="Received command to update data source" url=http://pyroscope:4040
logger=datasource t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67433261Z level=debug msg="Applying default URL parsing for this data source type" type=phlare url=http://pyroscope:4040
logger=sqlstore.session t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67461233Z level=debug msg="reusing existing session" transaction=true
logger=secrets.kvstore t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67481805Z level=debug msg="got secret value from cache" orgId=1 type=datasource namespace=Pyroscope
logger=sqlstore.session t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.67483685Z level=debug msg="reusing existing session" transaction=true
logger=sqlstore.session t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.675196969Z level=debug msg="reusing existing session" transaction=true
logger=sqlstore.session t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.680797361Z level=debug msg="reusing existing session" transaction=true
logger=secrets.kvstore t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.68130112Z level=debug msg="secret value updated" orgId=1 type=datasource namespace=Pyroscope
logger=sqlstore.transactions t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.68132252Z level=debug msg="skip committing the transaction because it belongs to a session created in the outer scope"
logger=sqlstore.transactions t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.6813886Z level=debug msg="skip committing the transaction because it belongs to a session created in the outer scope"
logger=secrets.kvstore t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.687266791Z level=debug msg="got secret value from cache" orgId=1 type=datasource namespace=Pyroscope
logger=accesscontrol.evaluator t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.729860369Z level=debug msg="matched scope" userscope=datasources:* targetscope=datasources:uid:phlare
logger=secrets.kvstore t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.730420729Z level=debug msg="got secret value from cache" orgId=1 type=datasource namespace=Pyroscope
logger=datasources t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.75003998Z level=debug msg="Querying for data source via SQL store" uid=phlare orgId=1
logger=secrets.kvstore t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.75029442Z level=debug msg="got secret value from cache" orgId=1 type=datasource namespace=Pyroscope
logger=tsdb.phlare t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.750416739Z level=debug msg="CheckHealth called"
logger=context userId=0 orgId=1 uname= t=2023-08-25T00:27:12.752653816Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/datasources/uid/phlare/health status=400 remote_addr={local-machine-addr} time_ms=3 duration=3.089555ms size=59 referer=http://{my-cloud-infra-ip-addr}:3000/connections/your-connections/datasources/edit/phlare handler=/api/datasources/uid/:uid/health
logger=ngalert.scheduler t=2023-08-25T00:27:20.000481563Z level=debug msg="Alert rules fetched" rulesCount=0 foldersCount=0 updatedRules=0
```

It is the logs when I send a healthcheck via grafana web dashboard.

Comment: What healthcheck in Pyroscope datasource is saying? Check browser network console and check which request is failing, what is response code,... Are you mixing http/https? Increase log level and check Grafana logs.

Comment: @JanGaraj
Hi Jan, thanks for replying. First, the healthcheck api sends a GET request to `http://cloud-infra-url/api/datasources/uid/phlare/health` But it returns `400 Bad Request`. And there is no mixing http/https.

Comment: Crucial details are still missing - Grafana debug logs.

Comment: @JanGaraj I just added the logs when I trigger healthcheck api via `Save & test` button on grafana web gui!

Comment: It works for me. Try `docker-compose pull` first to download current latest images

Comment: Ah!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot... It resolved... Finally I know the reason is the versions of image.... Thanks a lot

Comment: Do not [edit] the question and put "Resolved" into the title or the text; instead create an answer (self-answering questions is allowed and encouraged). You should rollback your last edit and put the content in an answer.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for your feedback. Jan remoed **Resolved)** from title and I creaeted answer by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

- Check the versions of images before.
- I used `docker compose pull` command to get the latest image versions, so this issue is resolved

---

Thanks to @JanGaraj, and @MT0